# Controle de acesso em sistema

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, sql

Como que faz para que cada usuário tenha um produto, cliente, etc individualmente em um login?Ex:  O usuário joão não ver o cadastro do samuel.

Answer (score 1):

Basta que, no ato do cadastro, você insira sempre o ID do usuário em questão. Na hora do login a mesma forma, pegue os dados referentes apenas aquele login